# controlling tick limits and direction in scale_colour_gradient in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using `scale_colour_gradient` with a `limits=` argument and a transformation to a log scale. I want the scale gradient to end exactly in those ticks, and have the ticks face outward rather than inward. Is this possible?

For example:

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Sepal.Length)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(3,8), trans=log2_trans())
```

I'd like the scale to start exactly at 3 (i.e. show no colors with values less than 3) and end exactly at 8 (show no values higher than 8) and have the ticks facing outward (preferably only on the right side of the scale, like in [this figure](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-c0ERyVMySF4/T8uv0r32JEI/AAAAAAAAAB0/C2peEeGZXAI/s400/Heatmap6.png) except not horizontal). The limits are important since in real data sometimes you clip values based on a cutoff and want to colour only the points that are in that range, so it's confusing to have a scale bar that shows colors outside the range (since points were selected to be in that range only.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a (built-in) option to alter the colorbar ticks in the manner you describe. But I think this hits the rest of your points:

```
ggplot(iris) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Sepal.Length)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(3,8),
                          breaks = round(seq(3,8,length.out = 4),1),
                          trans=log2_trans()) + 
    guides(colour = guide_colorbar(draw.ulim = FALSE,draw.llim = FALSE))
```

You could remove the ticks entirely with `ticks = FALSE`. For different styles of tick marks you'd probably have to hack the grid code itself.